# Railsconsole: in `require': cannot load such file — readline (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

when i run the my project rails that time i got this error :-

```
bin/rails:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/Desktop/module/school/config/boot (LoadError)
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what version of ruby are you running., also post the content of  of the following files: bin/rails and config/boot.rb

Comment: my ruby version is ruby 2.3.1                                                                      files : bin/rails#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'